# How to get Places with MATE single-menu layout

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, menu-bar

MATE’s Traditional layout has the three-item menu (Applications/Places/System, known as “Menu Bar”), which provides a convenient way to access network shares, bookmarked folders and certain default folders (Home, Documents etc.)—but it lacks a search function and does not respond to the system key.

Then there’s the Familiar layout, which has the “Brisk Menu”—a single-item menu which can be launched with the system key and has a search function but lacks all the entries found in the Places menu. I need to launch Caja as an application and then navigate to my target.

Is there a way to get a layout that provides all of the following?

- Preferably a single item on the panel
- Launches with the system key
- Sarch function
- Convenient access to places, including bookmarks

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution called “MATE Menu” (as of Ubuntu MATE 18.04, there are four different menu options):

- Right-click the top panel and choose **Add to Panel…**
- Choose **MATE Menu** and click **Add**
- Right-click the new menu that appears and choose **Preferences**
- On the **Places** tab, select **Show GTK+ bookmarks**
- Remove the previously selected menu from the panel

The menu can be customized further, e.g. by adding more places (which will appear only in the menu) or showing recent documents.